# How to load SAP Analysis Excel file into Microsoft PowerApps

Tags: excel, powerapps, sap-analysis-for-office

Does someone have experience with loading data from an SAP Analysis Excel file into PowerApps? I would like to load the data from such a file into Microsoft PowerApps and create an app with it. However I get the following error:

[image]

I think it's due to the SAP formating of the Excel sheet.
I tried to load a "simple" Excel file (no SAP Analysis) with dummy data and formating table and that worked. I was able to load that into PowerApps.

I also tried to Excel table format the SAP Analysis file but that works only partly. The headers and some data remain SAP formated. And after a refresh of the file the formats are back to SAP format.

However I would like to use the data from generated from SAP Analysis. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean Excel file corresponding to SAP Analysis for Microsoft Office?

Comment: give a file sample, it may be that your file is corrupted and/or wrongly formatted